# OpenERP file downloads with no extension

Tags: python, xml, odoo, openerp-7

I have created a file and stored in database. When I download the file, it has no extension. Also, the downloaded file comes with name "className_ID" instead of the File name specified.

**Here is my python code**

```
class dev_history(osv.osv):    
_name = 'dev.history'
_order = 'id desc'

_columns = {   
    'doc_file':fields.binary('Document'),
    'doc_name' : fields.char('Name',size=32),
    }
_defaults = { 'doc_name': "Device History.doc", }

dev_history()
```

**XML Code:**

```
<field name="doc_file" string="File" readonly="1" filename='doc_name'  attrs="{'invisible':[('doc_name','=','')]}"/>
<field name="doc_name" readonly="1" invisible="1" colspan="2" attrs="{'invisible':[('doc_file','=','')]}"/>
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Please help!